# Why using a variable name "temp" considered a bad practice?

Tags: language-agnostic

Whenever i put up a code for review from professional programmers they tend to point out that "using a variable named temp is bad" but no one seems to know why.

Why is it considered bad ?

Comment: Did you ask *them*? And what did they say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`temp` indeed doesn't mean anything useful. A better question is: does it have to?

Without knowing the context (how is it used in your code?), it's hard to say what it's for, and whether `temp` is a good name. **If you use a variable often or non-locally, the name must be descriptive.** A name like `temp` can be fine if you use it, say, three times in three adjacent lines.

```c
void swapIntPointers(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

It's immediately obvious what this function should do (from its name) *and* what it actually does (from its structure). In this specific case, I strongly *prefer* short (and automatically nondescript) names. I'd even say that `temp` may be a little too long here ;)

However:

- If you use the variable often, it's apparently important, and 'deserves' a better name.
- If you use the same variable in places in the function that are far apart (non-local), it helps programmers to 'remember' the meaning when you give it a recognizable name.

Comment: Koodos, this is a great way to distinguish the good and bad uses of `temp`. Too many people dogmatically believe it is a poor name. The reality is that it's perfect for storing a mutable return value for short iterative functions like `sum` or `reverse order`. Also great where `b, a = a, b` is invalid. Locality is the most important aspect because the lifetime shouldn't extend far beyond the declaration.

Answer (score 8):

It's because `temp` suggests something about the longevity of the variable (temporary) but nothing about the meaning or significance of its content.  Variables are generally best named to reflect what their underlying value is intended to represent.

Comment: What it **is**, not **how it is used**.